# How to get one instance of dependency while it injected several times in different classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I need to get one instance of OwnerService, because in Dataloader class I load some data to that instance and in OwnerController class I have to get loaded data. But in OwnerController there was no data. I printed out the instances and receive different ID of instances

Dataloader class

```
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
   private final OwnerService ownerService;
   public DataLoader() {
      ownerService = new OwnerServiceMap();
   }
   @Override
   public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println(ownerService);
   }
}
```

```
@RequestMapping("/owners")
@Controller
public class OwnerController {
    private final OwnerService ownerService;

    public OwnerController(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }

    @GetMapping({"", "/", "/index"})
    public String ownersIndex(Model model) {
        System.out.println(ownerService);
        model.addAttribute("owners", ownerService.findAll());
        return "owners/index";
    }
}
```

I need one instance of Bean in several injected classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `DataLoader`, you are not injecting `OwnerService`. Instead, the constructor directly creates an instance of class `OwnerServiceMap` (which is presumably a class that implements interface `OwnerService`):

```
public DataLoader() {
    ownerService = new OwnerServiceMap();
}
```

Instead, inject it into `DataLoader`, in exactly the same way as you are doing in `OwnerController`:

```
public DataLoader(OwnerService ownerService) {
    this.ownerService = ownerService;
}
```